# How do I clear all items from a TreeTable?

Tags: java, vaadin

In my widget I have a Vaadin [`TreeTable`](https://vaadin.com/docs/v7/framework/components/components-treetable.html) that uses `HierarchicalContainer` as its data source.

```
treeTable = new TreeTable();
treeTable.setContainerDataSource(hierarchicalContainer);
```

It has multiple columns and half of this table are editable fields. I need to clear those fields on some button click.

I have found two solutions for now:

1. Use `removeComponent` and remove `treeTable` instance from the widget and later reinitialize it.
2. Use `removeAllItems` on the container and fill the container with the data.

What approach should I use? Or is there another way to do that?

Comment: You cloud just use the `setContainerDataSource` with the new data. It is more efficient than removing the `TreeTable`from the UI and then adding it again

Comment: @AndréSchild do you mean to initialize `hierarchicalContainer` again?

Comment: this depends how you construct your container, but yes, you have anyway to do this.

Comment: I would just remove all items from the container.